# Difference between 'a place good for' and 'a good place for'

Tags: adjectives, placement

Take a look at these sentences:

> a. This is a place good for business.
> b. This is a good place for business.

Is there any difference between the meanings of the above sentences?

Answer (score 1):

Your second sentence usually means that this place is a good place to conduct business. The first is incorrect as it stands, but corrected to *This is a place that is good for business* it would have the same meaning.

Comment: Thank you so much. Would you say 'a safe place from the storm' or 'a place safe from the storm'? It seems to me that 'from' is different from 'for'...

Comment: I would say "This place is safe from the storm." Following this construction, "This place is good for business" can refer to something like a beach being good for business in the surf shop in the nearby town, as well as having the meaning in my answer.